# Why does paging reset grid datasource (EntityDataSource)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

I have a Gridview whose datasource is an EntityDataSource. AllowPaging is set to true (see code). On the page there is a DropDownList as well. When the page loads initially the grid is populated with all the data in the associated data source [unfiltered]. When / if the user selects an item from the DropDownList, the data in the Gridview gets filtered accordingly.

The problem is when I select a page from the newly filtered list, the filter gets taken away some how, so instead of getting the next page of the filtered list, I get the next page of all the data. How do I correct this?

------the opening grid declaration-----

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAthleteInfo" runat="server" DataKeyNames="AthleteUid" DataSourceID="dsAthleteInfo"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="dl-grid-heading" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvAthleteInfo_RowCommand"
    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
.
.
.
</asp:GridView>
```

---------the data source tied to the grid----------

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsAthleteInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=MBSCEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="MBSCEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="utathleteinfoes" AutoPage="true">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

-----------the "filtering" of the grid data on a change of the DropDownList selection-----------------

```
protected void ddlTeams_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlTeams.SelectedIndex > 0)
        dsAthleteInfo.Where = "it.SportUid = " + ddlTeams.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    else
        dsAthleteInfo.Where = "it.SportUid >= 0";

    dsAthleteInfo.DataBind();
}
```